# How can I logon to windows automatically using a smartcard?

Tags: windows, registry, smartcard, autologin

Is it possible to logon to Windows automatically using a smartcard? I don't want to have to enter the PIN when the computer boots up.

This is supposed to be like the auto-login feature where you can store the default username and password in the registry so you aren't prompted and are logged in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no full answer, the snippets may help a bit. Actually a smart card for login is intended to provide a two factor authorization. You must *posess* the card and *know* the PIN. If I understand correctly, you want a one-factor authorization, where just the posession of the card is sufficient. From the card view it is possible, to have an authorization key on the card, which is always usable. This may happen either by directly stating an access rule "ALWAYS" for the key in question, or by requiring a PIN but have this PIN disabled (like for mobile phone SIMs). I have no idea, whether your target version of Windows accepts a disabled PIN and consequently does not pop up an entry form but directly starts the login process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm trying to do is automate the login process. I hoped that there would be a way to automate the entry of the PIN at the Windows login screen but I haven't been able to find any method as yet.